# multiply the number in the array if it matches the given one

Tags: swift, reduce

I have an array like this, and I need to multiply a number if it is 3, but in the end reduce eliminates all numbers equal to 3, and multiplies the rest. How do I fix this ?

```
 let arr = [2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 10, 4, 2, 13]

 let aaa = arr.reduce([]) { $1 == 3 ? $0 : $0 + [$1 * 5] }

//[10, 20, 5, 20, 5, 50, 20, 10, 65]
//[2,4,15,1,4,15,1,15,10,4,2,13] need this
```

Comment: You should use map.

Answer (score 1):

You should use map instead of reduce

```
let arr = [2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 10, 4, 2, 13]

let result = arr.map { $0 == 3 ? 15 : $0 }
// [2, 4, 15, 1, 4, 15, 1, 15, 10, 4, 2, 13
```

Or if it should work for any multiple of 3

```
let result = arr.map { $0.isMultiple(of: 3) ? $0 * 5 : $0 }
```

Comment: Actually it says "multiply a number _if it is_ 3" so I think it's only 3 exactly which means you could actually just return 15 directly...

Comment: That is true, @JoakimDanielson, just used to so many questions being multiple(of:). I've updated my answer.